Problems with compiling with llvm and gcc, while trying to link external libraries to EngineCore.lib and finally linking core to EngineEditor.exe
Help me I Cherno's followed game engine series and branched to add 3D capabilities. I am having issues while linking libraries, at first I just wanted to share Game Engine code with friends, but not everyone has big ass Visual Studio, so I started experimenting with gmake2 from premake and it turns out code is not linking properly with llvm and gcc compilers. What happening is libraries like ImGui, glfw are linking to EngineCore.lib and EngineCore is linking to EngineEditor, on msvc it is working fine but on other compilers EngineEditor.exe is having linking errors saying unresolved external symbols and if I try linking ImGui and other libraries directly to Editor it is saying duplicate symbols. So i moved ImGui to compile entirely inside EditorCore and it worked but to do that I had to remove ImGui as a project. Now that ImGui is taken care of, other libraries which are linking to Core are giving same errors. What can I do to solve as I can have separate projects and their libs while linking properly to the main editor and core?

Hello! Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, debugging c++ compiling/linking is nearly impossible for the format of this site as this involves a lot of tiny details and are hard to reproduce for us.

@Vaillancourt thank you for reading my question! I don't know how to approach this. If you link an external library to your application core library and then link it to your exe but doing that is throwing resolved external symbols, how would you approach it?
Here the link to my repository https://github.com/VedantS-32/ConstellationEngine/tree/experimental
Also i am middle of implementing model rendering so please excuse my codebase.
